# Drawing graphics on a panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to draw graphics on panels, but I am not sure how I would go about doing that.

I have tried creating a class that extends the JPanel and overrided paintComponent, and some other methods, but nothing gets rendered at all.

Here is my code:

```
edit:

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lesson1 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -198253288329146091L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Lesson1 frame = new Lesson1();
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Lesson1() {

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974584127539186578L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 500);
            }

        };

        contentPane.add(panel);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 123456789L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }

        };

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(panel_1);

    }

}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I have tried everything I could. Thanks!

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples. Start with the working examples and customize the painting code as required.

Answer (score 0):

## Mistake #1

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

and

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

Before you do anything else, you need to learn and understand what the layout managers actually do and why `null` layouts are naive and not recommended (especially when you're just learning).

Start by taking the time to go through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Remove `contentPane.setLayout(null);` and change `panel.setLayout(null);` to `panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` and you will see an immediate change.

In fact, you really don't need `panel`, as the default `contentPane` of a `JFrame` is already setup to use `BorderLayout`.

This means you can get rid of `panel.setBounds(73, 52, 231, 143);`

## Mistake #2

Okay, this is more of an oversight, but, when you start customising components, you need to provide sizing hints, which allows the layout managers to make decisions about how best to layout your component in relationship to other components and based on it's own internal rules.

To this end, you should, at the very least, override the `getPreferredSize` method (avoid the `setXxxSize` methods as these can lead to unexpected results if used incorrectly)

Add...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1001, 1001);
}
```

to `panel_1`

This now means you can do something more like...

```
Lesson1 frame = new Lesson1();
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

and the window will pack it self around the component (and be centred on the screen) and you can get rid of `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);`

> Alright, anyways I tried but have no luck making it so I can set panels in a specific position :/

Layout management in a GUI environment is part science, part voodoo, part black magic

Pixel perfect positioning is an illusion in modern UI development. There are so many factors which go into determining "how" a component should be positioned on a single platform, let along across multiple platforms, you'd spend the rest of your live constantly adding "hacks" to account for the infinite number of possible edge case.

This is why any decent UI framework abstracts the concept, Swing uses the layout manager API for this purpose, iOS (and MacOS) use Auto layout, etc...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lesson1 {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Lesson1();
    }

    public Lesson1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

            add(new RectPane(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
            add(new RectPane(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(new RectPane(), gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
            add(new RectPane(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
            add(new RectPane(), gbc);
        }

        // This is just to demonstrate how the layout works when the avaliable
        // space is larger then the desired space, you don't need this
        // and should get rid of it and just let the layout manager calculate
        // it's desired size based on it's content
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

    }

    public class RectPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

    }

}
```

Understand, `GridBagLayout` IS the most complex layout manager in the standard API, but it is the most flexible.  You're also not confined to a single layout manager, you can use compound layouts to create very advanced interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have updated my code and posted it on the question for you to review it :) Also, I still have 1 more question. When I add the setLayout, it will not add component into panel, it will just show the component. But when I remove the layout settings, it works just fine by showing the parent(container) then the component on it. So I removed them, is that right? And how can I disable centering panels? So that for example this http://prntscr.com/modba4

Comment: First, I've gone the most simplest route to "just make it work". Most layout managers actual centre their components in one way or another, if you want a different position, then you might need to look towards a more flexible layout manager, like `GridBagLayout`, which will provide you with more control, but it is also the most complex layout manager available in the standard API

Comment: @o6707448 Also, be careful with changing your question, as now my answer doesn't match the original question

Comment: Alright, anyways I tried but have no luck making it so I can set panels in a specific position :/

Comment: @o6707448 You're missing the point - pixel perfect positioning is an illusion in modern UI development.  There are so many factors which go into determining "how" a component should be positioned on a single platform, let along across multiple platforms, you'd spend the rest of your live constantly adding "hacks" to account for the infinite number of possible edge case.  This is why any decent UI framework abstracts the concept, Swing uses the layout manager API for this purpose.